# Database table Error when run python manage.py migrate command

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration

I have cloned a django project.
I have installed all dependency and also change dbname ,username, password.
When I run this command **python manage.py migrate** or **python manage.py makemigrations** then I got the following error.

```html
imsaiful@code:~/Desktop/abdul_bhai/fuelark_app-master$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: notification_ID

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

```html
File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/imsaiful/Desktop/abdul_bhai/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: notification_ID
```

I have worked django earlier. The new table always created inside database after we run the migration command. What should I do?

Comment: maybe someone has messed up with migration files... it is hard to tell without reading the actual migrations

Comment: I have deleted all the migrations now and now connect to sqlite3 still I am getting table does not exist.

Comment: can you add full traceback, please?

Comment: added some initial part. Hope this may give you some idea.

Comment: If possible, please delete all migrations files ( except __init__ in migration dir) then run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`then run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: did same but getting table error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: notification_ID